# Undo "Disable autofill for [app]"

Tags: settings, auto-fill

I am referring to the system-wide password autofill feature that was introduced in Oreo. In one app, I accidentally fat-fingered the prompt; instead of pressing "Fill with [autofill service]," I pressed "Disable autofill for [app]." How can I undo this? I want to be able to use autofill with that app again.

These did not fix the problem:

- Changing the autofill service to Google and then back
- Uninstalling and reinstalling the app in which I want to use autofill

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Long tap the username field, tap the three dots next to "Paste" and select autofill. There will be an option "Enable autofill for " where you can re-enable it.

Tried on Android P

Comment: Thanks. I realized that I didn't specify that I was using Android P.